# ¿Cómo editar registros guardados en FireBase?

Tags: javascript, firebase

Según tengo entendido, Firebase almacena registros en una colección de datos (array); esa es la razón por la que puedo ejecutar la función `.push()` a mi referencia en Firebase, para poder agregar un nuevo registro.

Todo bien hasta ahí. Sucede que ahora quiero editar, por ejemplo, el registro número 3 que se encuentra almacenado en Firebase.

¿Cómo puedo cambiarlo? LIntenté usando la misma estructura para los arrays, ejemplo:

```js
var Empleado1={
  nombre: 'Ada',
  apellido: 'Lovelace'
};

var Empleado2={
  nombre: 'Mikhael',
  apellido: 'Santos'
};

var EmpleadoSuplente={
  nombre: 'Empleado',
  apellido: 'Suplente'
};

var empleados= [Empleado1, Empleado2];
empleados[0]= EmpleadoSuplente;
```

Al parecer ningún error; pero al revisar en el apartado `"Database"` no se modificó nada. ¿Qué sucedió? ¿Hay alguna manera de hacerlo?

Comment: Podrías agregar más detalle, como json desde firebase

Answer (score 0):

Es muy complejo editar arrays ya que los mismos se almacenan como JSON Arrays que no son manipulables, se puede pero realmente no amerita el esfuerzo.
La recomendación sería estructurar los datos de manera que todos esos nodos (en tu caso empleados) sean hijos de un nodo padre. Asi, podrás escuchar a cambios puntuales de cualquier empleado y poder acceder/editar cada empleado puntualmente.
La estructura sería algo como

```
- empresa 1
     - <employee UUID>
         - nombre
         - apellido
     - <employee UUID>
         - nombre
         - apellido
- empresa 2
     - <employee UUID>
         - nombre
         - apellido
```